# Why is turtle not drawing in Python 3 in Line class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, turtle-graphics

I am writing a Line class to draw a line given the coordinates of two points. However, when I run this program, the turtle does not draw anything. Is there an error in the way I defined my Draw() method or called it? I'm not very familiar with Python3 and classes. Here is my code:

```
from turtle import *
g = Turtle()

class Line():
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.X1 = x1
        self.Y1 = y1
        self.X2 = x2
        self.Y2 = y2
        self.Draw(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    def getX1():
        return self.X1

    def getY1():
        return self.Y1

    def getX2():
        return self.X2

    def getY2():
        return self.Y2

    def Draw(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        g.penup()
        g.goto(x1, y1)
        g.pendown()
        g.goto(x2, y2)

def main():
    theLine = Line(0, 0, 100, 100)
    theLine.Draw()
```

Comment: Every method in a class that is not marked as `staticmethod` or `classmethod` should have at least one parameter, usually called `self` (stands for the object itself). So all of your getXX methods should accept one argument `self`

Answer (score 0):

The function `Draw` you defined takes 5 arguments (`self`, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`). But what you want is to get the coordinates information from the `Line` object.

That's why the `self` parameter exists. The `self` parameter is the object itself, so instead of using `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2`, you want to use the values stored in the object, like so:
`self.x1`, `self.y1`, `self.x2` and `self.y2`. after you change the these, you should also remove the unnecessary arguments of the function (everything except `self`)

Final code

```
def Draw(self): # Removed the arguments
    g.penup()
    g.goto(self.X1, self.Y1) # Go to the starting point stored in the object
    g.pendown()
    g.goto(self.X2, self.Y2) # Go to the endpoint stored in the object
```